# how to position an image correctly, html css

Tags: html, css, image

I'm creating a website with a full image background, and I have a number of images I want to lay over the top, but if I align the images so they look good on my resoultion anyone with a smaller screen or bigger instantly the images look like they were just ploop'd ontop.

Heres my example - http://www.xronn.co.uk/avatar

Do you know of methods I can use so images will be standing on parts of the background for all screens, or atleast so they look decent.

thanks

Comment: Media queries and `position: fixed`?

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question?

Answer (score 1):

To display an HTML element at a specific position you can use a positionning method called ***absolute positionning***. This is done by setting the `position` CSS property to `absolute`. In cases such as yours, it's better than to hack the natura html flow with `margin` and `float` attributes, which are not meant to serve this kind of purposes.

This enables you to use the `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` to absolute. These four attributes specify the distance between an edge of the element and the same edge of it's reference. The reference is the nearest ancestor which position is `relative` or `absolute`.

You can specify values of these attributes in px, em, %, etc...

Of course, you will not specify more that 2 attributes of `left`, `width` and `right` for obvious reasons, and the same for `top`, `height` and `bottom`.

In your case, it might be good to specify the `bottom` attributes and `left` or `right` with percentages.